# How to do something with string items in list with Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with numerical and string values, like this:

```
vals = ["1", "2", "A"]
```

I want to replace all sting values in this list with "0". So that the new list is: ["1", "2", "0"].

Why does not this work?

```
[i for i in vals if str(i).isnumeric() else "0"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid. While using `if` and `else` in list comprehension, they should come before `for` loop

```
vals = ["1", "2", "A"]
new=[i if str(i).isnumeric() else '0' for i in vals]
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a **wrong syntax** for comprehension, the `if else` condition should be checked before `for` if you want to have the values conditionally:

```py
>>> [i if str(i).isnumeric() else "0" for i in vals ]
['1', '2', '0']
```

But if you want to have only the values that satisfy the condition, then only you can have `if` after `for <item> in <iterator>` without the `else` part, which is similar to `filter` builtin:

```py
>>> [i for i in vals if str(i).isnumeric()]
['1', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how [.isnumeric()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isnumeric) is used.
Instead, use .isdigit():

```
[i for i in vals if str(i).isdigit() else "0"]
```